# If $x$ and $y$ have the same distribution , does $x + y$ or $x - y$ has the same distribution?

Tags: probability

If random variables $x$ and $y$ have the same distribution and they are independent. Does $x + y$ or $x - y$ has the same distribution? 
Any proofs please?

Comment: *The* questions would have been: “Under what conditions have $X\pm Y$ the same distribution?

Comment: Which distribution are you looking for ?

Comment: For starters $\mathbb{E}[x+y] = 2\mathbb{E}[x]$ while $\mathbb{E}[x-y] = 0$...

Answer (score 1):

Typically not. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then the moment generating function/characteristic functions of $X$ and $Y$ is the product of the moment generating functions of $X$ and $Y$ (that is, their densities/mass functions convolve). Also, note that $X$ and $-Y$ are also independent and you can apply the previous result to find their distributions.

$X+Y$ and $X-Y$ can have different distributions, obviously, even if $X,Y$ are i.i.d. - let $X$,$Y$ be Exp(1). Then, $X+Y$ is supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$ while $X-Y$ can be negative. Note that neither of the $X+Y$ and $X-Y$  distributions are Exp(1) (the first is Erlang(2,1)).

Obviously if $X$ and $Y$ are from distributions which are symmetric about $0$, then $-Y =_d Y$ and thus, $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ have the same distribution. (This result only depends on $X$ and $Y$ being independent, and $Y$ having a symmetric distribution, actually).

There is a family of distributions known as [Levy $\alpha$-stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution), for which linear combinations lie within the same family (but with different parameters). The simplest example is the normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Toss two coins - do you count that the same distribution as tossing a single coin (use values $0,1$ and add them)?